# Disable onTapped on TabBar on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to prevent the tab from moving even if I tap on TabBar.

```
TabBar(
        controller: this._controller,
        tabs: <Widget>[
          new Tab(
            text: "A",
          ),
          new Tab(
            text: "B",
          ),
          new Tab(
            text: "C",
          ),
        ])
```

Comment: Do want to disable the tab action?

Comment: @IshanFernando yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to add listner to tab click and then change the index to 0 again. In this we need to add controller and we can set index through that.

```
    class TabBarDemoWidget extends State<TabBarDemo> with TickerProviderStateMixin{


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _tabIndex = 0;

    var tab = TabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 3,
      vsync: this
    );

    void _handleTabSelection(){
      setState(() {
              tab.index = _tabIndex;
            });
        }
    tab.addListener(_handleTabSelection);




    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        initialIndex: 0,
        child: TabBar(
               labelColor: Colors.teal,
               controller: tab,
               tabs: [

                GestureDetector(
                  child:Tab(
                  icon: 
                  Icon(
                    Icons.directions_car)) ,
                  onTap: (){
                    _tabIndex = 0;
                  },
              ),GestureDetector(
                  child:Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)) ,
                  onTap: (){
                    _tabIndex = 0;
                  },
              ),GestureDetector(
                  child:Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)) ,
                  onTap: (){
                    _tabIndex = 0;
                  },
              )
              ],
            ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it. but, not working as expected. 
`GestureDetector` does not work  `onTap` except on the icon.

Comment: I tested and it works. Can you explain which part is not work?

Comment: sorry..., I has removed `addListener`. it works. but, maybe, `GestureDetector` not needed. https://gyazo.com/5e5b61036e009cb37ce20a4c41de4937

Comment: This isn't a good way to handle tabs. Wrap IgnorePointer over TabBar and it will prevent from updating the state.

Answer (score 26):

Just wrap the TabBar in an IgnorePointer.

Comment: This should be the correct and easiest answer.

Comment: this only works for all tabs, but what if you want to disable a specific tab present in the tabbar ?

Answer (score 17):

I have a more elegant solution:

```
TabBar(
  onTap: (index) {
    if (_controller.indexIsChanging) { 
      _controller.index = _controller.previousIndex; 
    } else { 
      return; 
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: Nope, this will move to the previous tab when you tap the current tab which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Resolved @DatTran comment with `if (_controller.indexIsChanging) { _controller.index = _controller.previousIndex; }  else { return; }`. It does nothing when tapping the active tab, otherwise, it stays on the selected tab.

Answer (score 9):

If you're embedding the `TabBar` in the bottom of an `AppBar`, you'll need to implement `PreferredSizeWidget`. This is easily achieved:

```dart
class ReadOnlyTabBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final TabBar child;

  const ReadOnlyTabBar({Key key, @required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IgnorePointer(child: child);
  }

  @override Size get preferredSize => this.child.preferredSize;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`TabBar` has a function `onTap`, you can do as below to not change tabs on tap.

```
TabBar(
            onTap: (index){
              setState(() {
               _tabController.index = 0; 
              });
            },
            controller: _tabController,
          ),
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to disable onTapped in TabBar, just use IgonreOPoiner widget,
wrap needed widget into IgnorePointer, and paste `ignoring:true`, to disable tap, click and e.t.c

```
IgnorePointer(
   ignoring:true,
   child:TabBar(
tabs:[
Tab(
child:Text("1"),),
Tab(
child:Text("2")),
])`
```

Answer (score 2):

@Rob Lyndon gave perfect answer.

This is another one like that only. 
But in this we are not creating one more class

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    bottom: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize:
          Size.fromHeight(_kTextAndIconTabHeight + indicatorWeight),
      child: IgnorePointer(
        child: TabBar(
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a gesture detector to the tab that you want to disable. Set onTap as null to disable tap. Look at the example provided below!

```
TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(child: Text("15")), //enabled
            Tab(child: GestureDetector(child: Text("16"), onTap: null), //disabled
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: does not work, you can still select(tap) the tab

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the tab widget with GestureDetector, and follow the code!!

```
   TabBar(
                    automaticIndicatorColorAdjustment: true,
                    tabs: [
                      const Tab(
                        child: TextWidget('Official'),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: const Tab(
                          child: TextWidget('PF,ESI'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                    tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
                    isScrollable: true,
                  ),
```